# What type of connector does the GROVE system use?

Tags: sensors, pins, wires

What type of connector does [GROVE](http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove_System/) use?

I'm interested in wiring some old sensors so they're compatible with GROVE, so I first need to identify the connector so I can buy the housing and pins to crimp. It looks to be some type of JST connector, but there are [many different sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector), each with incompatible pitches and a lot of retailers often advertise them incorrectly. Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation of the connector on Seeedstudio's site.

Comment: The link to the GROVE has changed: http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove_System/

Comment: I was about to ask the same question. This was driving me crazy, it seems the information is written nowhere!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like the Grove connector is proprietary. I emailed Seeedstudio, and they directed me to [this datasheet](https://statics3.seeedstudio.com/images/opl/datasheet/3470130P1.pdf). Unless I'm reading it incorrectly, it doesn't appear to correspond to any type of JST connector, although it's similar. It has 2mm pin spacing, which would make it closest to the [JST-PH type](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Prototyping/ePH.pdf), but all the other dimensions are slightly different.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link appears to have died.

Comment: It is indeed proprietary and Grove's decision to use proprietary connectors deserves nothing but criticism.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the updated link on the seed website.

http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/wiki/File:3470130P1.pdf

Also note that Digikey now stocks seeedstudio stuff.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/seeed-technology-co-ltd/110990030/1597-1082-ND/5482560

http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/seeed-technology-co-ltd/110990037/1597-1083-ND/5482561

Comment: The first link gives me a 404 error, do you mean https://statics3.seeedstudio.com/images/opl/datasheet/3470130P1.pdf? As this is a bit of a link only answer, including an image of the contents of the pdf would be a great idea.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the OEM part is NS-Tech 1125S-4P: [Wire to Board connector > PITCH 2.00mm > 1125 Series](http://www.nstech.com.cn/en/products/product_202201151603323190.html)

Good luck finding a vendor!

Comment: Not sure why you're downvoted, when Grove's link to OPL for the 4-pin connector has NSTech datasheets, and references the 1125S family in T/H and SMD.

https://www.seeedstudio.com/opl.html
https://statics3.seeedstudio.com/images/opl/datasheet/3470130P1.pdf
https://statics3.seeedstudio.com/images/opl/datasheet/3470140P1.pdf

While it has similarities to the JST PH series, it is not the same.  The prominent latching features on the NSTech/Grove do not exist in the JST.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a JST connector. There are ramps on the side of the connector that won't allow the grove/seeed cables slide into the connectors. After I shaved/cut off the ramps, to allow them to fit into the connector, I found that the pins are slightly offset in there vertical alignment. 
This appears to be a custom connector. However, if anyone knows better, I would be interested, but the answer is not JST.

Comment: @Greenonline Not really.  Gerben made a statement, but that statement is *obviously* wrong as the pin pitch does not even match.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I received some definitive information from Seeed's tech support, as posted in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is proprietary.  It makes it hard to build your own custom length cables. But then if you are, you probably don't need Grove modules in the first place.  I would use them more if I could build a cable.  The JST PH 2.0 definitely doesn't work well, even if you shave it down.  The PH also doesn't have the locking tab that the Grove connector does. It's interesting that some of the Grove boards have both JST PH 2.0 as well as Grove connectors for different purposes (e.g. LiPo battery connector)

Answer (score 2):

These look like equivalents to the Molex Sherlock-series connectors ([www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=sherlock](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=sherlock)). I've ordered a Grove-compatible board that should get here Monday. I'll try connecting a Sherlock connector to it, and if I remember I'll give an answer back here as to whether it mates and locks properly. The pin pitch and pin dimensions are the same, I can tell that already, and it sure "looks like" a Sherlock connector.

Comment: It mates with a Sherlock connector, but the latching mechanism doesn't latch. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not a jst-connector - please have a look at them here [http://www.amazon.com/Seeedstudio-20-pack-Grove-Connectors/dp/B00BB0I7V2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BB0I7V2) (the seeed website seems to be down at the moment). I Eagle you would search for a TWIG-4P-2.0. 
These guys have 4PINs which are connected to ground and VCC + the data lines depending on the sensor you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here there are GROVE connectors in SMD and a drawing is included: [Grove - SMD Universal 4 pin connector (10 Stück)](http://www.ebay.de/itm/Grove-SMD-Universal-4-pin-connector-10-Stuck-/152174510967?hash=item236e4ec377:g:ItwAAOSwWfFXj1jf).

[image: Three pin connector diagram]

Comment: Unfortunately, the diagram in the link shows a three pin connector, and not a four pin connector as used by the Grove system.

Answer (score 1):

Following up from Cerin's [answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9030/what-type-of-connector-does-the-grove-system-use#answer-18583), as the link to the datasheet on Seeed's website appears to have expired, I also contacted the technical support team at Seeed.

They sent me, I assume, the same datasheet. Here is a link to it, [110990030-model](https://gr33nonline.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/110990030-model.pdf), and here is a screenshot, should the link die in the future:

[image: Grove connector datasheet]

Along with the datasheet, I also received the following information:

> 11006005(OLD) -->110060161(NEW)
>
> Grove - Light Sensor change to V1.2, which had another light sensor.
>
> Others same.
>
> 101020040(OLD)-->101020175(NEW)
>
> Just some performance optimization.

From MCU's [answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9030/what-type-of-connector-does-the-grove-system-use#answer-26551), and the linked eBay item for the [Grove - SMD Universal 4 pin connector (10 Stück)](http://www.ebay.de/itm/Grove-SMD-Universal-4-pin-connector-10-Stueck-/152174510967?hash=item236e4ec377%3Ag%3AItwAAOSwWfFXj1jf&nma=true&si=jpWiQ5brMZFPqTrPvqibsJAPgbs%253D&orig_cvip=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557), the diagram below also shows the dimensions. However, it is quite clearly only a **three pin** connector, and *not* the **four pin** connector used in the Grove system:

[image: Grove SMD connector]

See also [Grove connector](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2016/11/16/grove-connector/).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

YEONHO_ELECTRONICS_20037wr

YEONHO_ELECTRONICS_SMH200

YEONHO_ELECTRONICS_YST200

or

CJT CONN A2008 WR S 4P / A2008 H
......

Answer (score 1):

This connector [A2005(PHB-SMD)](https://www.lhecn.com/a2005/) Series has become common in China, I have not found a supplier in the USA that carries it yet.

There is a similar connector, the [A2008 series here](http://www.cnjmp.cn/en/YH-200-LED-light-bar-connector/A2008WR-S-NP.html).

A2005 images without-latching-plug:
[image: A2005 images]

Answer (score 1):

I might have found at least one of the many possible manufacturers that make these types of connector. The manufacturer is Boom Precision Electronics and you can buy the connectors through [LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/).

Here are the links to four of the connectors on LCSC.

[Vert. THT 4-Pin 2.00mm](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Wire-To-Board-Wire-To-Wire-Connector_BOOMELE-Boom-Precision-Elec-HY-4A_C146064.html)
[RA THT 4-Pin 2.00mm](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Wire-To-Board-Wire-To-Wire-Connector_BOOMELE-Boom-Precision-Elec-HY-4AW_C146068.html)
[Vert. SMD 4-Pin 2.00mm](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Wire-To-Board-Wire-To-Wire-Connector_BOOMELE-Boom-Precision-Elec-C161188_C161188.html)
[RA SMD 4-Pin 2.00mm](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Wire-To-Board-Wire-To-Wire-Connector_BOOMELE-Boom-Precision-Elec-C146060_C146060.html)

Disclaimer: I never bought these connectors listed above so I never got the chance to try and mate the grove cable housing with it. It however does seem to fit the dimension and shape based on the drawings.